# PHP preg replace issue with looping

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need  a little help with the below code. I have a field on a table where I need various tags replaced, and I have identified the regex pattern needed to target the specific area. This code pulls these out and strips them into the format I want BUT... it assigns them all the same "imageId" in the body -- the last one in the array. I know it is not looping in the correct way, just need another set of eyes on it. I feel if it went through the Body and replaced one tag at a time instead of in the middle of the for loop it may do what it is supposed to. Currently the field body looks like this:

```
<text:image id="12345" blah blah blah />

lots of text here

<text:image id="123456" blah blah blah />

lots of text here

<text:image id="7890" blah blah blah />
```

I want it to look like this:

```
<text:image id="12345"/>

lots of text here

<text:image id="123456" />

lots of text here

<text:image id="7890" />
```

Here is the code:

```
$textToReplace2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, body from t1");
while($row2 = $textToReplace2->fetch_array()) {
  $t1_id = $row2["id"];
  $body = $row2["body"];

  $oldBody = $body; 

  $pattern = '#(text:image id=)"\d+(.*)(/>)#';
  preg_match_all($pattern, $body, $matches);

  foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    $id=$match; 

    preg_match('#\d+#', $id, $nextMatches);

    foreach ($nextMatches as $nextMatch) {
      $imageId=$nextMatch; 

      $newBody = preg_replace($pattern, 'ID:'.$imageId, $body);

      $newEscapedBody = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $newBody);

      $update2 = "UPDATE T1 SET body = '$newEscapedBody' where id = '$t1_id'";
      $updateResult2 = mysqli_query($conn, $update2);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do all of those brackets being closed?

Comment: copy paste problem, they are there

Comment: `UPDATE T1 SET body = '$newEscapedBody' where id = '$t1_id'` Here you are updating the record with id `$t1_id` in every step of the loop. In every step, you are updating the same record again and again. So, the value that you are updating in last step of the loop stays in your table.

Comment: yeah but even removing that update, dumping newEscapedBody shows the first text id to be set each time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeuch!

There are several ways to improve this. I don't have my regex tester to hand but something like....

```
while($row2 = $textToReplace2->fetch_array()) {
  $t1_id = $row2["id"];
  $body = $row2["body"];
  $replace='$1>'; // some experimentation needed to find correct index
  $new=preg_replace('#(<text\:image id="(\d+)")([^>]+)>#U', $replace, $body);
  $newEscapedBody = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $new);
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on the index approach you took? just trying to learn

Comment: Read up on pcre's, particularly sub expressions